# Xpages - Document refreshing with old values

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I have some code, that if a user selects a "NO" answer on a certain field (Q1), it removes the answers of sub question related to Q1, and also hides them in the UI.

This works fine, and I do a partial refresh on the div containing all the questions. However, when I then click on the same question selecting answer "Yes" which then shows all the sub questions, so the user can answer them again, they still have the old values attributed.

When I remove the fields, the backend document reflects this correctly, but then when I click the question which then shows the fields again in the UI, they appear in the backend document again, with their original value. If I do a context.reloadPage() at the end of my code, everything works as expected, but this breaks other functionality and I only want a partial refresh. Any ideas? Thanks

```
try{

    if (compositeData.onClickCode) {
        compositeData.onClickCode.invoke( facesContext, null );
    } 

    document1.save();   
    var fieldName:string = compositeData.fieldName; 

//Blank all IFM fields if user selects no IFM *CHANGE FIELDS ARRAY TO GET FROM KEYWORD*     
if (fieldName == "Q1") {
 print("Yes Q1");
    if(document1.getItemValueString(fieldName)=="No") {
     print("NO IFMS");
        var questionsIFM = ["Q1a", "Q1b", "Q1c", "Q3IFM", "Q3bIFM", "Q3cIFM", "Q3dIFM", "Q4", "Q4a" ,"Q5IFM", "Q6IFM", "Q6aIFM", "Q7IFM",
        "Q7aIFM", "Q7bIFM", "Q8", "Q8a", "Q9IFM", "Q9aIFM", "Q9bIFM", "Q10IFM", "Q11IFM"];  

        var len = questionsIFM.length;
        for (i = 0; i < len; i++) { 
            print("Field Name: " + questionsIFM[i]);
            document1.removeItem(questionsIFM[i]);
        }
            document1.save();
            //context.reloadPage();
    }
}

    var guidanceOptions:string = "";    
    if (compositeData.guidanceOptions) {
        if(@IsMember(document1.getItemValueString(fieldName), compositeData.guidanceOptions)){
            guidanceOptions = document1.getItemValueString(fieldName);
        }   
    }   

    viewScope.guidance = compositeData.fieldName+guidanceOptions;

}catch(e){
    openLogBean.addError(e,this.getParent());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of changing the backend document you could update the datasource with `doc.setValue('fieldName','')`

Alternativly, you could change the scope of the datasource to "*request*", this forces the datasource to reload the backend document for every request.

**EDIT:**

Here is an example for updating the datasource directly (Button 'Clear') which always works and updating the component (Button 'Update').

If the button 'Reload' is clicked, changes to in the fields are "stored" in the component. The button 'Update' does a partial refresh (which hides the input field), so the value is lost.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view
    xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
    <xp:this.data>
        <xp:dominoDocument
            var="document1"></xp:dominoDocument>
    </xp:this.data>

    <xp:div
        id="refreshMe">
        <xp:inputText
            id="inputText1"
            value="#{document1.foo}"></xp:inputText>

        <xp:inputText
            id="inputText2"
            value="#{document1.bar}"
            rendered="#{javascript:facesContext.isAjaxPartialRefresh() == false}">
        </xp:inputText>

    </xp:div>

    <xp:button
        value="Update"
        id="buttonUpdate">
        <xp:eventHandler
            event="onclick"
            submit="true"
            refreshMode="partial"
            refreshId="refreshMe">
        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:button>

    <xp:button
        value="Clear"
        id="buttonClear">
        <xp:eventHandler
            event="onclick"
            submit="true"
            refreshMode="partial"
            refreshId="refreshMe">
            <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:document1.setValue('foo', '');document1.setValue('bar', '')}]]></xp:this.action>
        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:button>


    <xp:button
        value="Reload"
        id="buttonReload">
        <xp:eventHandler
            event="onclick"
            submit="true"
            refreshMode="complete">
        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:button>

</xp:view>
```

Comment: Thanks - However I've tried both options, but still have the same issue. The previous value re-appears on the next partial refresh.....

Comment: Is an error raised? Just add a messages component in the partial refreshed area.

Comment: No errors, dropped an error message control on which shows nothing, and all my code logs to openLogger for errors, and nothing there either. Everything seems to run fine, the fields get blanked correctly, but the next partial refresh brings back the old values. context.ReloadPage() at the end of my code resolves the error but I don't want to do a full reload

Comment: I suspect its still using the in memory DataSource as partial refresh doesn't update the xspDoc from the back end.......

Comment: @ChrisRichards:I have updated my answer with a working example.

Comment: Hi Sven, apologies for the late response, I've been on leave. I still couldn't get it to work, so I've changed my approach. At the end of the onChange code on my radio button I've added viewScope.clearFields="Yes". This means, I still get my modal box pop up after a user has clicked as only doing a partial refresh, then on the close button of the modal i check that variable, if its "Yes", I blank it, and do a context.reloadPage(). Not the most elegant, but this scenario only happens on one field and I have no time left to try anything else! Thanks for your suggestions as always!

Answer (score 0):

I might be late to this party, but I found a way to force a reload from the back-end document. All you have to do is change the id for the dataSource a little, by adding or removing a "0" prefix to the documentId. Something like this:

```
return (viewScope.idPrefix? "0":"") + param.documentId
```

and when you want to force a reload during a partial refresh, just set

```
viewScope.idPrefix= !viewScope.idPrefix;
```

Don't forget to set ignoreRequestParams to true.